# Can we develop Mobile Application via Thingworx PTC?

Tags: android, mobile, iot, thingworx

I am new to IoT and Thingworx platform.
I need to know

1. What are the advantages of using Thingworx?
2. Can we able to develop Mobile application using Thingworx? If yes, how can we do that? Any Links?

I have downloaded and installed Thingworx Foundation and trying to develop  some sample applications referring the [developer portal](https://developer.thingworx.com/)

How can we show this mashups and data from any sensors in Mobile app.

Any Ideas Please.

Comment: If you want to build an App on ThingWorx, you have to do it on any development environment you want and leverage ThingWorx REST API in order to call services. Mashups are for Browsers not for Mobile Apps.

Comment: In andriod SDK how can we bind this thingworx API. As I am new to thingworx Can you tell in brief? Any links available.

Comment: You need to register as Thingworx developer and you will be able to access to the API specification.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the Android SDK provided by Thingworx to develop apps which communicate with the Thingworx foundation server.

A beginner level tutorial can be found from here:

- https://developer.thingworx.com/resources/guides/thingworx-android-sdk-reference

Documentation can be found from the below link:

- http://support.ptc.com/help/thingworx_hc/thingworx_edge_sdks_ems/#page/latest%2Fandroid_sdk%2Fc_android_sdk_help_center_intro.html%23

Similar SDK exist for iOS too.